# QGIS Projections

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I am new to the GIS world and have faired pretty well with ArcGIS 9.3, learned and still learning on the job. I would like to get a better handle on QGIS though. I linked the files from my dropbox. I tried the on the fly projection and changing the projection of the following file:
http://db.tt/Nuc9Bni4

I need the aforementioned file to project and line up with the following boundry file:
http://db.tt/Ij6MEyDz

Thanks in advacnce for any input.

Answer (score 8):

Load both shapefiles into QGIS.

Right-click on one of them and choose 'set project crs from layer'.
[image]

Open the poject poperties, tab CRS and check 'enable on the fly crs transformation'.
[image]

Now, both layers would align.